# How to tap on particular coordinates(x-axis, y-axis) in IOS?

Tags: automation, adb, appium, ui-automation, appium-ios

I have found the same for the android using adb commands, such as:
adb shell input tap 100 500, It will tap on the coordinates(100,500) on android device.
Is it possible to do the same for IOS device, How?

Answer (score 0):

Using appium you can use the `TouchAction` from the client library as follows :

```
TouchAction tapCoordinates = new TouchAction(driver); //where driver is AppiumDriver
tapCoordinates.tap(x,y).perform();
```